# What does the '=' operator do in this context? sqrtf(1 - (t = t / d - 1) * t);

Tags: javascript, objective-c, actionscript, syntax

The following code is part of an easing equation. I'm just interested in the syntax.

`sqrtf(1 - (t = t / d - 1) * t);`

I haven't seen the '=' operator used like this before. What does it do in this context?

Edit: the code is from a well-known Robert Penner easing function, written in ActionScript:

```
static function easeOut (t:Number, b:Number, c:Number, d:Number):Number {
    return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't a mistake? If not, that's a really  convoluted way of writing `sqrtf(1 - (t / d - 1)^2);` and setting `t = t / d - 1` at the same time.

Comment: This looks really dangerous.

Comment: It's quite strange and awful, but thanks to the parentheses I do believe it's *not* undefined behaviour...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `=` operator here does what it always does.  In this case it modifies `t` (setting it to `t / d - 1`).  The value returned from that part of the equation will be the new value of `t`.

This becomes confusing because `t` is used later in the equation, and I wouldn't be sure that every compiler would treat it the same. *ie* is the third `t` going to use the old value or the new value?

I would avoid writing equations in this way.  It's lazy and I don't see any good reason to do it.

Comment: As the expression is evaluated left-to-right, I would expect it to use the new value. Are there any compilers not guaranteeing that?

Comment: I don't know.  I just don't like it for that very reason, and I would never recommend people write equations that way just because they want it to appear on one line instead of two.